# What is the best approach to implement "login page" + "business logic page" (see details) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need to create an application with a login-screen which should pass login/passwd data to the second screen and, afterwards, visually switch to that second screen with rendering some data based on entered login -- while disabling "tab-switching" and swipes if no login data is provided.

My first approach was - to create a single "HomePage" with TabBar + TabBarView on it, with three tabs, with three widgets and some logic behind.

TabBarView has the disabled swipes:

```
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

I have tabcontroller implemented which tries to get login/password data AND current tab index and avoid user from navigating to tabs 2 and 3 if there are not login data entered.

The problem is - I do not fully understand concepts of callbacks and globalkeys so I forced to get everything available from stackoverflow and simply from google results to try on. So my code is pretty "clugged" now and, it is not working (it can't switch the TabBarView to the second page using TabController's ".animateTo(1);") and I am in the state of "throw everything away and start from the beginning".

So, again, I need to "preserve" two strings ("loginData" and "passwdData") between navigation attempts.

Could someone help me and show me the best implementation directions? Maybe I should rewrite my application to the concept of using a stand-alone "LoginWidget" as the HomePage "entry point" and, on successful login - do a Navigator.push to display the "second" page, **where** TabBar/TabBarView will be displayed with two tabs.

Maybe, someone did something similar, like:

1. getting login/password input from user;
2. do some http-request with that data;
3. display received JSON-data (or contents of a file received from FTP) in a TabBar/TabBarView with the possibility to dynamically update tabs.

Please help T_T

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:mask_text_input_formatter/mask_text_input_formatter.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key, required this.loginData, required this.passwdData}) : super(key: key);

  final String loginData;
  final String passwdData;

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin
{
  late TabController _tabController;
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
  }

  _handleTabSelection() {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = _tabController.index;
      if (widget.passwdData.isEmpty ||
          widget.loginData.isEmpty) {
        _tabController.animateTo(0);
      } else {
        _tabController.animateTo(1);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Application"),
            foregroundColor: Colors.black,
            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
            bottom: TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                indicatorWeight: 5,
                tabs: const <Widget>[
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.login)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.currency_exchange)),
                ]
            )
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: const <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: LoginWidget(),
            ),
            Center(
              child: MainInformationWidget(), // not actual widget name
            ),
            Center(
              child: AdditionalInformationWidget(), // not actual widget name
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}

// Login widget
class LoginWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginWidget> createState() => _LoginWidget();
}

class _LoginWidget extends State<LoginWidget> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final loginController = TextEditingController();
  final passwdController = TextEditingController();
  String _login = "...";
  String _passwd = "...";

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    loginController.dispose();
    passwdController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var maskFormatter = MaskTextInputFormatter(
        mask: '#####',
        filter: { "#": RegExp(r'[F0-9]') },
        type: MaskAutoCompletionType.lazy
    );

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                child: Center( // Just a logo
                  child: SizedBox(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 150,
                      child: Image.asset('assets/img/logo2.jpg')),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                child: TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Login is required!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  maxLength: 5,
                  inputFormatters: [
                    UpperCaseTextFormatter(),
                    maskFormatter,
                  ],
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Login',
                      hintText: 'F1234'
                  ),
                  controller: loginController,
                  onSaved: (val) => _login = (val)!,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 15, bottom: 0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty){
                      return "Password is required!";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Password',
                      hintText: 'Enter your password here.'
                  ),
                  controller: passwdController,
                  onSaved: (val) => _passwd = (val)!,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 250,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.redAccent, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                ),
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: formSubmit, /////////////////////////////
                  child: const Text(
                      'Login',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  void formSubmit(){
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
        _formKey.currentState?.save();
        SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide'); // We don't need keyboard onscreen anymore.
        setState(()
            {
              HomePage(loginData: _login, passwdData: _passwd,);
            }
        );
        _HomePageState()._tabController.animateTo(1);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What I understand is, you have a tabbar and you do your login in one of these tabs. If user did not logged in, other tabs are not reachable? If this is the case, why not make your login page an entire screen if you will not let users do anything unless they log in?

Comment: @aoiTenshi you are correct, I am using a tabbar/tabbarview as you described. The main problem is - how to pass login/password data between widgets if I decide to put login logic in a separate widget. Like, in my code - I can remove the reference to `LoginWidget()` from the first tab and remove that tab completely, ok.I still need to check if actual login data was entered and pass it somehow to the code serving the two other tabs.

Comment: You can save user datas into sharedpreferences and get them globally. This way you can also make a user logged in when launching app.